# DAX most recent date

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

I currently have a table in Excel with

```
FileName | LastDownloaded
-------------------------
File1        02/23/2021
File1        02/14/2021
File1        02/07/2021
File2        02/23/2021
File2        02/14/2021
File2        02/07/2021
etc..
```

And I just want most recent date

```
FileName | LastDownloaded
-------------------------
File1        02/23/2021
File2        02/23/2021
File3        02/23/2021
etc.
```

Been trying different measures in DAX and different tools in Power Query to try and accomplish this.

Comment: Are you looking for a measure or a calculated table or what?

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query you would just `GroupBy` `FileName` with a `Max` operation

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"FileName"}, {{"Latest Date", each List.Max([LastDownloaded]), type nullable date}})
```